# How Do You DO A Plist Array Display with iPhone?

Tags: iphone, arrays, cocoa-touch, plist

I have looked high and low for sample Plist display code and can't seem to find any that does what I want to do. I know it can't be too hard, but I am new to Plists.

I have the following Array in a Plist and I can't seem to get the right command to display the information. Am I doing something wrong in my Plist setup? It compiles fine but no Data gets to the iPhone Simulator.

What would be the normal way of displaying the info?

I have a condition set:

If condition one
    then    display "+0+1"
else
        display "+0+2"

---

*What I am hoping it to display is:
*               "this is one"
*               "this is two"
*               "this is three"
*       else display
*               "555-555-1234"
*               "555-555-0000"
*               "555-555-5555"

---

- MY PLIST IS AS FOLLOWS
  *
- - Key             Type                Value
    *Root                   Dictionary          (2 items)
- *+0+1               Array               (3 items)
- *Item 0         String              "this is one"
- *Item 1         String              "this is two"
- *Item 2         String              "this is three"
- *+0+2               Array               (3 items)
- *Item 0         String              "555-555-1234"
- *Item 1         String              "555-555-0000"
- *Item 2         String              "555-555-5555"
  *

`// read property list into memory as an NSData object

        NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];

    NSString *errorDesc = nil;

    NSPropertyListFormat format;

// convert static property list into dictionary object

    NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization   propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves  format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];`

`// assign values

    self.item1 = [temp objectForKey:@"name1"];

    self.item2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"name2"]];

    // display values

    bigCheese.text = disp1;

    numberZero.text = [disp2 objectAtIndex:0];

    numberOne.text = [disp2 objectAtIndex:1];

    numberTwo.text = [disp2 objectAtIndex:2];`

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
NSString *file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data" ofType:@"plist"]; 
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:file]; 
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Array"]; NSLog(@"%@", array);
```

It's simple, so less chances to do something wrong.

Comment: That looks like the kind of solution I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I got errors: Did you mean: [[NSDictionary <or> [NSDictionary   ??

Comment: sorry, only one [, I made typo

Answer (score 0):

Once you get a dictionary get all values for that dictionary. In your case, get all values from the temp dictionary. It should return you an array containing two arrays.

NSArray *valueArray = [temp allValues];

Now you have two arrays and if you want to access "555-555-5555", do like this:

[[valuesArray objectAtIndex:1] objectAtIndex:2];

Or if you are sure that "name1" and "name2" are the keys of your dictionary you can access it this way:

[[temp objectForKey:@"name1"] objectAtIndex:2];

Once you get this info then it is up to you to decide how you want to display it. I suggest you to DEBUG and see if the dictionary and array objects are created properly first. Not sure what are those disp1 and disp2 in the sample code you posted..

Comment: I appreciate you expanding on the concept. It's a little hard for me to get my head around it. I have about 5 tables that have about 60 items each for a total of about 300 items.